# Multiple dimensions in a php array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I wanna know if it's possible to have multiple dimensions in a php array. I have 7 columns in my database and I need the data to a respective variable
code:

```
$months = Array();
    $months = ['January'=>array(), 'February'=>array(), 'March'=>array(), 'April'=>array(), 'May'=>array(), 'June'=>array(), 'July'=>array(), 'August'=>array(), 'September'=>array(), 
                        'October'=>array(), 'November'=>array(), 'December'=>array() ]; 



    // Connect to MySQL
         if ( !( $database = mysql_connect( "localhost",
            "root", "" ) ) )                      
            die( "Could not connect to database </body></html>" );

    // open Events database
         if ( !mysql_select_db( "Events", $database ) )
            die( "Could not open Events database </body></html>" );

            foreach($months as $month => $arr) {



            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posted_events WHERE Month_ = '$month'  ") 
                    or die ('Error updating database because: '.mysql_error());
            }
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                    $months[$month][] = $row['DayNum'];


    }
}
```

So you can see `$months` is a two dimensional array containing a month and the days for that month in my database. But in my database I have other stuff like EVENTNAME, STARTTIME, ENDTIME, DESCRIPTION ETC...and I want to store those in a way like:

May 13th 12pm have the following events => all the events. 
Help please, thanks.

Comment: Your arrays can have as many dimensions as you want.

Comment: Maybe you want something like `$months[$month][] = $row;`?

Comment: but how would I get the information stored in like for example: May 12th at 2PM?

Comment: `var_dump($months);`; this will show you what your array looks like.  Probably something like `$months['January']['DayNum']`.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem or the question is. You don't even say what's the database schema. And your code formatting and indentation is all broken to the point that I still don't see where you use the `$i` variable from the `for` loop. Moving on!

Comment: Is DayNum field of the table an integer, as in a number between 1 to 31?

Comment: sorry that for was supposed to be removed, see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is same mess around your `for` cycle: `$i` is unused and `while` is outside the cycle. If you need something like Month - Day - Hour - Event, you need a four dimension array, like:

```
    foreach($months as $month => $arr) {
        for($i = 1; $i <=31; $i++){ // you can still work around this "for" cycle: it isn't the best option
        $months[$month][$i] = array(); // third dimension
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posted_events WHERE Month_ = '$month' AND DayNum='$i' ") 
                     or die ('Error updating database because: '.mysql_error());
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                    $months[$month][$i][strftime('%H',$row['STARTTIME'])] = $row;    // fourth dimension
        }
        mysql_free_result($result);
        }
}
```

You'll get ENDTIME and DESCRIPTION as the fourth dimension of the array. You can find their values like `$months['January'][13]['12']['DESCRIPTION']` or `$months['January'][13]['12']['ENDTIME']`.

About the `strftime('%H',$row['STARTTIME'])`: this is a function that gets only the hour from $row['STARTTIME'], assuming this is stored as a TIMESTAMP data type. You can substitute it with `substr($row['STARTTIME'],0,2)` if data type is TIME.

I also suggest you to use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql client, as it is deprecated in PHP 5.5 and newer versions.

Comment: and if I want to add ENDTIME and DESCRIPTION have other while statements with those added rows? Also could you explain the use of '%H'?

Comment: Yes, edited right now. One while is enough for all fields, and you can even work to remove the "for" cycle and make things more efficient.

Comment: could you show me a workaround? @F. Haymar d'Ettory cause I can't think of any..thanks

Comment: @Kay: No :P You should use just one query with all the row sets (remove WHERE statements). This eliminates both the "foreach" and the "for" cycle. In the "while" cycle you can distinguish the Month_, the DayNum and the hours (as shown) from each to complete the code (using "if" or a "foreach" inside the while). 
At the moment you are doing 12*31=372 queries to the database. You can do the same with 1 or 12 queries (it depends by your code). Do not use * in the SELECT, but declare specifically each field you need.
The spirit is to learn and be creative, not to have your code done :p